# Angular - values from subscribed observable not displayed on mobile device

Tags: angular, mobile, observable

I created an angular service that receives data from a websocket server in JSON format. In a component, this observable is subscribed to and stored in an array. The connection to the socket server works, I can display the data just fine on my desktop browser. However, when I connect with my mobile webbrowser I cannot see the data. Other values from the component display just fine.
What am I missing?

These are the relevant parts of the service:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import * as socketIO from "socket.io-client";
import { Observable, fromEvent, map } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root",
})
export class SocketService {
    private socket;

    constructor() {
        this.socket = socketIO.io("http://localhost:5000");
    }

    onData(): Observable<SensorData[]> {
        return fromEvent(this.socket, "on_data").pipe(map((value: string) => JSON.parse(value)));
    }
}

export interface SensorData {
    name: string;
    subject: string;
    unit: string;
    value: number;
}
```

This is the component:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { SocketService, SensorData } from "src/app/socket.service";

@Component({
    selector: "app-view-sensors",
    templateUrl: "./view-sensors.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./view-sensors.component.scss"],
})
export class ViewSensorsComponent {
    constructor(private socketService: SocketService) {}

    data$: SensorData[] = [];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.socketService.onData().subscribe((datastream) => {
            this.data$ = [];
            for (let entry of datastream) {
                let a: SensorData = { name: entry.name, subject: entry.subject, unit: entry.unit, value: entry.value };
                this.data$.push(a);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the template:

```
<div class="card-container">
    <ng-container *ngIf="data$">
        <mat-card class="card" *ngFor="let datapoint of data$">
            <mat-card-header>
                <mat-card-title class="title-subtitle">
                    {{ datapoint.subject }}
                </mat-card-title>
                <mat-card-subtitle class="title-subtitle">
                    {{ datapoint.unit }}
                </mat-card-subtitle>
            </mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-content>
                {{ datapoint.value | number : "1.0-0" }}
            </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

First I suspected that the issue is related to angular material, but removing all material items from the template did not help. The values still would not display on my mobile browser. Also, when I wrote static values directly into the mat-cards in the template, everything displays as it should be.

I also thought that maybe it has to to with the interpolation but when I defined values in my component and accessed them in the template with the {{ }} interpolation, it also showed up fine.

I have disabled all the css for the component but still, the observable data does not display.

My next guess is that I'm doing something wrong with the subscription but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, the problem was how I exposed the websocket server in the backend and how I connected to it in angular.
Changing the ip address in `this.socket = socketIO.io("http://localhost:5000");` to my actual ip address (192.168.100.12 in this case) and exposing the socket server on 0.0.0.0:5000 did the trick. I figured it out when I could load the data from a local json file (using HttpClient), but not from an actual http server in the backend. After getting the http server to work I did the same configuration to the socket server and that was it.